# Horizontally scrolling gallery - CSS only

Tags: html, css

Here's a website showing exactly what I need: [kelseymcclellan.com](http://kelseymcclellan.com)

But it's not in **CSS**.

Here's a website that uses CSS only: [olivercurtisphotography.co.uk](http://www.olivercurtisphotography.co.uk)

But there are several limitations:

- the images are embedded as img

- the width of the gallery must be specified in px

Instead, I need

- the images to be divs

- the gallery to adapt independently to the number of images

Here's how I embed images:

**HTML**:

```
<div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url(image.jpg);"></div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.img {
    background-size: cover;
}

.ratio:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    padding-top: 66.6666667%;
}
```

I found a lot of answers that achieve something similar to what I need, but none of them is close enough.

How do I create a series of divs scrolling horizontally?

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox. Check the following code:

```css
#container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.img{
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.olivercurtisphotography.co.uk/projects/Volte-Face/Volte-face-01.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.olivercurtisphotography.co.uk/projects/Volte-Face/Volte-face-01.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.olivercurtisphotography.co.uk/projects/Volte-Face/Volte-face-01.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.olivercurtisphotography.co.uk/projects/Volte-Face/Volte-face-01.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.olivercurtisphotography.co.uk/projects/Volte-Face/Volte-face-01.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap a container div around your image divs, you can set the width of the container div to the width of all your image divs.

In the below snippet, as you can see, I set the `.img` divs to `200px`, and gave them a `margin-right: 10px`. Since I have 10 images, I can set the width of my div container to `calc(210px * 10)` (`210px` comes from the width of the image divs plus the margin, and `10` comes from the number of images).

It was also necessary to set `font-size: 0` on the container div. Without this setting, there is some unintentional whitespace between the images that breaks the perfectly calculated width of the container div.

See example:

```css
.img-container {
  width: calc(210px * 10);
  font-size: 0;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**: I just noticed your request to not explicitly set the width. You can set the container divs width to `max-content` to achieve this. See below:

```css
.img-container {
  width: max-content;
  font-size: 0;
}

.img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-container">
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
  <div class="img ratio" style="background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/200/100');"></div>
</div>
```

Full disclosure, the `max-width` property [doesn't appear to be supported in IE or Edge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width).